# Problem accessing server method within client side method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I've tried to use JQuery.ajax() to access the server-side method within the client-side event handler ..this is what my code looks like:

*Controller*

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult addDirectory(string directoryName)
        {
            Directory dir = new Directory();
          1-  dir.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
          2-  dir.dateAccessed = DateTime.Now;
          3-  dir.dateModified = DateTime.Now;
          4- dir.ImgURL = "~/Images/Folder-Add-icon.png";
          5-  dir.DirectoryName = directoryName;
          6-  dirRepo.addDirectory(dir);
          7- dirRepo.Save();
            return new JsonResult { Data = dir };

    }
```

*View*

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "Explorer/addDirectory", 
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {param1: name},

          complete: function() {
              alert("finished");
          },

          success: function(data) {
          alert("added");
         },

          error: function() {
          alert("error");
          },
        });
```

The problem is, the "error" method gets called always if I add 1-7 lines in the controller method .. if I comment them out the success method will get called, WHY?

Comment: Most probably, some exception is getting generated in those lines. Why don't you use VS to debug and step through the code.

Comment: After debugging I've found out that "directoryName" parameter is passing in as a null value .. !!

Comment: Well where does "name" come from in your JavaScript fragment above?

Comment: I've changed it to 
 data: {param1: "Dir"} 
and still getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

Just changed param1 to directoryName !